# How do I batch CSS selectors together?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The below CSS makes a div have a background color. What I am trying to achieve is this: when a user clicks on an anchor link then the link they've clicked highlights (on the same page). So in the example below if there was an achor link like this - `index.php#content-5` then the background becomes yellow (just like here on stackoverflow)

So it works - but is there a clever way to make all these div's batch together? I'm thinking something like `#content-1,#content-2,#content-3` etc - or is that the wrong approach?

Thanks!

```
#content-5 {
/*width: 75%;*/
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}

#content-5:target {
background-color: #ffa;
-webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: You could have just tried it! https://jsfiddle.net/peayweu8/

Comment: You should include the HTML. Since you are using `:target`, I'll assume your HTML is valid and say that you have very little flexibility. `:target` needs an id and those are limiting when it comes to CSS. I'd say you got it as good as it gets. I can't totally be sure unless you include HTML though.

Comment: Why you don't use a class instead of the ids on the CSS selectors?

Comment: What @goncalopinto said. The :target pseudo matches by id but it doesn't require an id *selector* qualifying it. If all the elements with similar ids are similar in nature anyways, that's the perfect use case for a class. Better still if you can write a selector matching just those elements without necessitating a class or an attribute selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with attribute selector. You can write all `#contentXXX` that you need, and you only need one selector.

**`[attribute^="value"]`** means that targets the element with the **`atribute`** value starting with **`value`** word. So in this case we can write **`[id^="content"]`** that means all elements that its attribute **`id`** starts with **`content`** word.

```css
a { 
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}
[id^="content"] {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}

[id^="content"]:target {
  background-color: #ffa;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<a href="#content1">Content 1</a>
<a href="#content2">Content 2</a>
<a href="#content3">Content 3</a>
<a href="#content4">Content 4</a>
<a href="#content5">Content 5</a>

<div id="content1">Content</div>
<div id="content2">Content</div>
<div id="content3">Content</div>
<div id="content4">Content</div>
<div id="content5">Content</div>
```

Comment: that worked really well - thanks for explaing it so well.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. you can just by putting commas you can apply the style rules to all the elements at once.

```
.box1,.box2,.box3{
  background: green;
}
```